# Can you override boostrap grid for just one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, mern, reactstrap

My entire app is nested within a bootstrap `container` along with `row` and `cols`

*App.js*

```
export default class App extends Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <NavigationBar />
          <Container>
            <Row className="justify-content-sm-center justify-content-md-center">
              <Col sm="7" md="7" lg="5" xl="5">
                <ProfileSidebar />
              </Col>
            
              <Col sm="7" md="7" lg="7" xl="7">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/tournaments/edit/:id" component={EditTournament} />
                  <Route exact path="/tournaments/:id" component={TournamentShow} />
                  <Route exact path="/tournaments" render={ () => <Redirect to="/" /> } />
                  <Route path="/player/:id" component={PlayerProfile} />
                  <Route exact path="/players" component={PlayerDirectory} />
                  <Route path="/users"  render={ () => <Redirect to="/players" /> } />
                  <Route path="/smash-news" component={SmashNews} />
                  <Route exact path="/" component={TournamentIndex} />
                </Switch>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
};
```

This is a tournament app, and the profile side bar is on the left-side of each page (as I wanted) but that means it restricts EVERYTHING to the right-hand side.

This is fine with me, except for my `tournament bracket` component.

It doesn't have it's own `route` or anything, as it is a child-component of `TournamentShow`.

I want to display everything in `TournamentShow` as is, but simply stretch the Bracket out to the whole screen, ignoring the constraints of bootstrap's grid.

Is this possible?

**This is how it looks right now, bracket trailing off to side**

[image]

**This is how it looks when I try some CSS**

*CSS file*

```
.bracket-position {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}
```

[image]

**but that screws it up for mobile size, moving the bracket to far-left without scrollable**

[image]

I'm sure there's some easy solution but my CSS abilities are lacking.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it up in a full-screen popup-like container div with a high z-index, position absolute and 100% width and height

Comment: like in a modal?

Comment: except for the popup/modal idea, no I have not.  But I am messing with position absolute, height/width properties

Comment: The "cleaner" way would be to implement a Context and wrap the whole app in a context provider which is then consumed by ```tournament bracket```. There you can toggle a boolean value for showing/hiding the Sidebar. Lookup React useContext if you are working with functional components.

Comment: I like that idea.  I'll work on that.  Thank you

Comment: Oh what am I saying, I don't know how to do that.  
The whole app is wrapped in a provider, tied to redux state.  But I'm unsure how to leverage anything in app.js

I'll update the post to show the full App.js code

Comment: Updated to include images

Comment: It's worth learning about responsive css if you wan't to do anything with CSS that is supposed to work on mobile as well. It's very easy. Google ```css breakpoints responsive```